# Recursive function call not adding values to list

Tags: python, list, recursion, memory

I am creating a Tensor by using lists and without the aid of libraries. The class **Tensor** has a method called, **shape_data**, which creates the Tensor by taking in the dimension and sublist.

```
  def shape_data(self, dim, sub):
    if dim >= len(self.shape):
      return
    elif (len(sub) == 0) & (dim < (len(self.shape) - 1)):
      for i in range(self.shape[dim]):
        sub.append([])
        self.shape_data(dim + 1, sub[i])
    elif len(sub) == 0:
      if len(self.data) > self.shape[dim]:
        sub = self.data[0:self.shape[dim]]
        self.data = self.data[self.shape[dim]:]
      elif len(self.data) <= self.shape[dim]:
        sub = self.data[0:]
        self.data = []
        while len(sub) != self.shape[dim]:
          sub.append(0)

data0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.1, 0.2, -3, -2, -1, 3, 2, 1]
shape0 = [5, 2]
tensor0 = Tensor(data0, shape0)
```

This is the output that I get
`[[], [], [], [], []]`
vs. what I want
`[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [0.1, 0.2], [-3, -2]]`

My question is, what am I missing here that the numbers are not being copied over successfully?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  I don't see how the class structure supports the problem you're facing, and I don't see the results of your tracing attempts.  See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Comment: you mean you want to do `return [data0[i:i+shape0[1]] for i in range(0,shape0[0]*shape0[1],shape0[1])]`?  Or do you need it to be recursive to handle more dimensional shapes?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I need it to be recursive to handle more dimensional shapes

Comment: @mlai The answer to this question is for future readers as well - so editing the answer and removing the fixed code "for learning excperience" is not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, that the problem is in following line:

```
sub = self.data[0:self.shape[dim]]
```

If you assign something to the variable sub , it will from then on point to the new value. The value it pointed to before that assignment (your original list) will stay unchanged.

If you, instead, assign something to elements of that list, this will change the original list:

```
sub[:] = self.data[0:self.shape[dim]]
```

Same affects this line as well:

```
sub = self.data[0:]
```

Here is corrected code:

```
class Tensor():
    
  def __init__(self, data, shape):
    self.data = data
    self.shape = shape
    self.tensor = []
    self.shape_data(0, self.tensor, 0)
    print(self.tensor)

  def shape_data(self, dim, sub, pos):
    if dim >= len(self.shape):
      return
    elif (len(sub) == 0) & (dim < (len(self.shape) - 1)):
      for i in range(self.shape[dim]):
        sub.append([])
        self.shape_data(dim + 1, sub[i], i)
    elif len(sub) == 0:
      if len(self.data) > self.shape[dim]:
        sub[:] = self.data[0:self.shape[dim]]
        self.data = self.data[self.shape[dim]:]
      elif len(self.data) <= self.shape[dim]:
        sub[:] = self.data[0:]
        self.data = []
        while len(sub) != self.shape[dim]:
          sub.append(0)
```